# GraphQL defaulting data causes infinite loops in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-hooks

so I have this code

```
const [localState, setLocalState] = useState<StateType[]>([]);
const { data = { attribute: [] }, loading } = useQuery<DataType>(QUERY, {
  variables: {
    id: client && client.id
  },
  skip: user.clients && user.clients.length === 0
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (loading || !data) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (data && data.attribute) {
    const sortedResult = data.attribute.sort((a, b) =>
      a.updatedAt < b.updatedAt ? 1 : -1
    );
    setLocalState(sortedResult);
  }
}, [data]);
```

the issue is when **useQuery** returns *empty(undefined)* result and data defaults to `{attribute: []}` **useEffect** keeps being triggered for forever, however when **useQuery** returns data (so it is not defaulted) **useEffects** is being entered only once. The solution for this problem was only to remove default parameter `= {attribute: []}` in the query so it looks like this:

```
const [localState, setLocalState] = useState<StateType[]>([]);
const { data, loading } = useQuery<DataType>(QUERY, {
  variables: {
    id: client && client.id
  },
  skip: user.clients && user.clients.length === 0
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (loading || !data) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (data && data.attribute) {
    const sortedResult = data.attribute.sort((a, b) =>
      a.updatedAt < b.updatedAt ? 1 : -1
    );
    setLocalState(sortedResult);
  }
}, [data]);
```

**Why defaulting parameter in useQuery makes useEffect being triggered for infinity?**

*(Important note to add - I tried to remove sort function, thinking that it mutates data object and causes reentering but it didn't change anything)*

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` is a new object at each render, as such re-triggering your `useEffect` that re-triggers an render and so on.

I don't think you need a `useEffect` here:

```js
    const { data, loading } = useQuery<
        DataType
    >(QUERY, {
        variables: {
            id: (client && client.id)
        },
        skip: user.clients && user.clients.length === 0
    });

    const localState = (!loading && data && data.attribute)
        ? undefined
        : data.attribute.sort(
              (a, b) => (a.updatedAt < b.updatedAt ? 1 : -1)
          );
```

should be enough

Comment: But if I don't use `useEffect` localState won't be updated after the promise from useQuery comes back with success. Also without state UI won't be re-rendered from my understanding.

Comment: @valentinIvanov you're already in rerendering (after `data` change), no additional rerendering (after state change) required

Comment: I don't think it is rerendering after data change, from graphql documentation(https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/) `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` is set as false by default and I don't set it to true anywhere in the code.

Comment: `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` is different, did you try the code ?
`useQuery` will re-render or you would not have a loop.

Answer (score 0):

> `const { data = { attribute: [] }, loading } = useQuery<DataType>(QUERY, {`

This declaration doesn't make a larger sense:

- not required as all rendering [and calculations] should be (and already is) blocked by `data` checking first;
- what with deeper nested values? next empty declarations? It leads to a dead-end;

It can create a new `data` object on every render ... but it shouldn't cause infinite rerenderings ... some other reasons?

You can break the effect loop by:

```
const [localState, setLocalState] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data && data.attribute && !localState) {
```

You can also use `onCompleted` event in hook:

```
const { loading } = useQuery<DataType>(QUERY, {
  variables: {
    id: client && client.id
  },
  skip: user.clients && user.clients.length === 0
  onCompleted: (data) => {
    if(data && data.attribute) {
      const sortedResult = data.attribute.sort((a, b) =>
        a.updatedAt < b.updatedAt ? 1 : -1
      );
      setLocalState(sortedResult);
    }
  }
});
```

... check/use `loading` and `{localState && <SomeResultView data={localState} />}`

Comment: That's much better solution than mine, thanks. But the problem whether I can use default parameters like so `= { attribute: []}` inside spread operator of useQuery or that's bad behaviour still bothers me. Just want to know for future use

Comment: You should avoid this kind of declarations ... YAGNI